# JQuery UI: draggable not revert to original position

Tags: jquery

css position `top` increase by approximately 10px every time the draggable is dropped OR reverts. For example,

First time I drag the apple from .sidebox to .dropbox, the apple ends up like this:

```
<div class="apple ui-draggable selected" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 10.1px;"></div>
```

Second time, I drag apple from .dropbox back to .sidebox or just slight move it and let it revert, apple is like this, note `top` increased by 10:

```
<div class="apple ui-draggable selected" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 20.1px;"></div>
```

Repeat drag-and-drop, `top` gets bigger and bigger:

```
<div class="apple ui-draggable selected" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 30.1px;"></div>
...
```

So my dear apple is drifting away from positon I want it to be until it says byebye to the page. What causes this?

The simplified code:

```
    // drag and drop
    $( ".apple" ).draggable({ 
        revert:true
    });

    $( ".dropbox" ).droppable({
        drop: handleDropbox
    });

    $( ".sidebox" ).droppable({
        drop: handleSidebox
    });

    function handleDropbox(event, ui) {
        $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        $(this).droppable( 'disable' );
    }

    function handleSidebox(event, ui) {
       ui.draggable.parent().droppable('option', {'disabled':false});
       $(this).children('h4').after(ui.draggable); 
    }
```

**EDIT: can't replicated it in jsfiddle, haven't figure out why..**

**Note that `.sidebox` position is fixed, might help?**

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
revert : function(event , ui)
    {

      if(event){
        return event;
      }
      else
        return !event;
    }
```

confusing question I am guessing you want to return to original position this will revert to original position regardless. add in the

```
 $("element").draggable(function({
// add revert here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

pls check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/4gFqh/7/

```
$( ".apple" ).draggable({ 
    revert:function(event,ui){  
        s=s+10;
        alert("my top position is "+s);
        $(this).data("draggable").originalPosition = {
                          top:s,
                          left:0
                                         };
                    return !event;
                             },
});
```

Comment: You totally misunderstand the question. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, see edit

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem using JQuery. Whenever my item would revert it was slowly sliding down the page. If I would have dragged and released a bunch of times, the element would eventually have "reverted" itself off the screen. My solution was to record the starting positions and reset the css properties after. My code is long in my real project so I will show an example (quickest fix I found that worked after coming across this 8 year old topic.) BTW - the real revert as shown in another answer DOES NOT always return the draggable to the same location (otherwise I wouldn't have a problem) - I think maybe this is because of borders? I honestly don't know.

```
$("myElement").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui){ startPos = $(this).position();},
    stop: function(event, ui){
        $(this).css("top", startPos.top);
        $(this).css("left", startPos.left);
    }
});
```

I hope that this helps someone... just know that it worked for me :)